# Sidekiq mailer job access to db before model is been saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, mailer

Probably the title is not self explanatory, the situation is this:

```
# user.points: 0
user.update!(points: 1000)

UserMailer.notify(user).deliver_later. # user.points = 0 => Error !!!!
```

`user` instance is updated and after that the Mailer is called with the `user` as a parameter, and in the email that changes are non-existent: user.points=0 instead of 1000

But, with a `sleep 1` just after the `user_update` the email is sent with the changes updated, so it seems that the email job is faster than updating data to database.

```
# user.points: 0
user.update!(points: 1000)

sleep 1

UserMailer.notify(user).deliver_later. # user.points = 1000 => OK
```

What's the best approach to solve this avoiding this two possible solutions?

- One solution could be calling `UserMailer.notify` not with the `user` instance but with the user values
- Another solution, it could be sending the mail in the `user` callback `after_commit`

So, is there another way to solve this keeping the user instance as the parameter and avoiding the `after_commit` callback?

Thanks

Comment: as Richard already responded: there must be a transaction around those statements. If you add your own, it is just a nested transaction, the changes wont be visible to other transactions until the outermost transaction is commited.
Can you show more code?

Comment: I think that the Transaction is not an option, I`ve already checked, the transactions are useful to ensure more than 1 table are saved in an atomic commit, this case is just one update of a table

Comment: Since the Job does not see the changes (or only after a timeout) it means that the change is happening in a uncommited transaction. From the little you show we can not tell you where the transaction is comming from and where it gets comitted. But you should only enqueue your job after that point and then the change will be visible to the job.
The timeout is not a reliable option. it might be 0.01s or 2s until the TX gets comitted.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the code is almost as it is in the example: the update saves a pair more of fields, and between the update and the email there are just a pari of inserts in other table/transaction.

Comment: a transaction with an update of 1 instance model of 1 record, as "rmlockerd" mention is redundant.

Comment: I'm applying as a solution, do not pass the instance model, instead the values, but another handicap I'm assuming now, is how to test it? *how to test a race condition?*

Comment: there must be a surounding transaction. where is this code? how is it called?
passing the values will work but is actually a hackish workaround.
since there is a transaction it might get aborted after your job is enqueued with, now, faulty values.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, Sidekiq runs copy of your Rails app in a separate process, using Redis as the medium. When you call `deliver_later`, it does not actually 'pass' `user` to the mailer job. It spawns a thread that enqueues the job in Redis, passing a serialized hash of `user` properties, including the ID.

When the mailer job runs in the Sidekiq process, it loads a fresh copy of user from the database. If the transaction containing your `update!` in the main Rails app has not yet finished committing, Sidekiq gets the old record from the database. So, it's a race condition.

(`update!` already wraps an implicit transaction around itself if there isn't one, so wrapping it in your own transaction is redundant, and doesn't help the race condition since nested ActiveRecord transactions commit only when the outermost transaction commits.)

In a pinch, you could delay enqueuing the job with something hacky like `.deliver_later(wait_until: 10.seconds.from_now)`, but your best bet is to put the mailer notification in an `after_commit` callback on your model.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :send_points_mailer

  def send_points_mailer
    return unless previous_changes.includes?(:points)

    UserMailer.notify(self).deliver_later
  end
end
```

A model's `after_commit` callbacks are guaranteed to run after the final transaction is committed, so, like nuking from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Agree, the `after_commit` is an option and actually I forgot to mention this possible solution as a solution that I'd like to avoid - in this case, the `user` model is too big and it should not be a task of the model itself -

Comment: Editing the question

Comment: Older versions of Rails had an `Observer` class that could watch for lifecycle events. It was spun out into a separate gem as of Rails 4. It doesn't look super-maintained, but you might be able to fork it and spruce it up for your purposes.

Comment: @rmlockerd i don't think a serialized version of the object is sent to sidekiq (if sidekiq is used with ActiveJob) but a GlobalId repesentation of the Model.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I’ll edit the answer. The effect is the same though; sidekiq loads a fresh copy of the model from the database when the job runs.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but I'm assuming you are using ActiveRecord? If so you likely need to assure to flush the database transaction before your sidekiq job is scheduled.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for yout response, Yes with ActiveRecord, but wrapping the changes in a Transaction does not solve the problem, I think it's more a question of threads than Transactions